# How to change date format from yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I wan to change date from `2017-11-25 23:35:08` (`yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`) to:

```
Sat Nov 25 23:35:08 IST 2017
```

I tried `echo 2017-11-25 | gawk '{print strftime("%c", $4)}'` but it's its not working.

Answer (score 3):

Using GNU `date`:

```
$ date -d "2017-11-25 23:35:08"
Sat Nov 25 23:35:08 CET 2017
```

The result will be in the local timezone (and in the local locale).

To explicitly request the IST timezone, use, for example

```
$ TZ=Asia/Calcutta date -d "2017-11-25 23:35:08"
Sat Nov 25 23:35:08 IST 2017
```

To ensure that you also get the POSIX/C locale's formatting:

```
$ LC_TIME=C TZ=Asia/Calcutta date -d "2017-11-25 23:35:08"
Sat Nov 25 23:35:08 IST 2017
```

---

Note that the `strftime()` function in GNU `awk` (and `mawk`) does not take a string as its second argument but a Unix timestamp. You would have to convert the time to a Unix timestamp using `mktime()` and then to the wanted format with `strftime()`. Calling `mktime()` would involve first breaking apart the input into separate year, month, day etc.

Also, `$4` will be empty in your call to the function (there is no fourth field in the input).

Comment: The date format might be different depending on users locale. I think prepending `LC_TIME=C` will take care of it.

Comment: @BLayer Yes, I added that too.